# How to find and replace value using power query?

Tags: excel, replace, powerquery

I would like to ask regarding replacing values in power query. [List of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD5rS.png)

I have attached an image of my table,the data is from pdf. I need to do vba in order to run one folder that contains 3000 pdf file. This is the testing by using only one pdf. So, I wanted to do group by rows so that I can transpose to make it as columns. My problem is, I have two column for postcode, one for registered address and another one is for business address. But when I do the group by, the postcode will combine as attached [After group by text.combine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DHJU.png). SO how do I replace postcode with two different name as example one is Postcode Registered Address and another one is Postcode Business Address.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You may want to check how to create a helper column of the list of values with an offset of -1, so it will show the address reference in the same row as the post code making it easy to differentiate

Answer (score 0):

You can create another conditional column and then remove the original column. using the output from conditional column you can achieve what you were looking for